# How to modify an item inside ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net

i want to concat(add) a string over an existing item here is the code:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double total = 0;
            double[] prices = {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0};

        CheckBox[] boxes = { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5, checkBox6 };

        listBox2.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " : ");

        for (int i=0;i<boxes.Length ;i++) 
        {
            if (boxes[i].Checked==true)
            {
                total += prices[i];
                listBox2.Items.Add(boxes[i].Text+" "); //it adds a new item 
            }

        }
```

the problem is with the output , every time it adds a new item i just want to add this line boxes[i].Text+" "  , to the same item 
thank you.

Comment: Don't tag questions VB.NET that have nothing to do with VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by:

> to the same item

Do you want to add it all to this one? `listBox2.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " : ");`

If so could you not just do this:

```
string name = textBox1.Text + " : ";

for (int i=0; i < boxes.Length; i++) 
{
    if (boxes[i].Checked == true)
    {
        total += prices[i];
        name += boxes[i].Text + " ";
    }
}

listBox2.Items.Add(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command `listbox2.items[0]+=boxes[i].Text+" "` with 0 being the index of the item you want to concatenate the string with.Because listbox2.items.Add will just keep adding items to your Listbox.

Best Regards.